# django-admin startproject gives SyntaxError

Tags: python, django

I tried to start a new project with django 4.0 After installing Django in environment folder (Anaconda/envs/taskman) I created a new folder somewhere in my e: drive and by using windows command line created a new folder Django_site. Then from this folder I typed in command line prompt: django-admin startproject lifetool and got the following:

```
    (taskman) E:\Projects\Django_site>django-admin startproject lifetool
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "E:\Programs\Anaconda\envs\taskman\Scripts\django-admin- 
    script.py", line 5, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    File "E:\Programs\Anaconda\envs\taskman\lib\site- 
    packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from django.core.management.base import (
    File "E:\Programs\Anaconda\envs\taskman\lib\site- 
    packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 13, in <module>
    from django.core import checks
    File "E:\Programs\Anaconda\envs\taskman\lib\site- 
    packages\django\core\checks\__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    import django.core.checks.translation  # NOQA isort:skip
    File "E:\Programs\Anaconda\envs\taskman\lib\site- 
    packages\django\core\checks\translation.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.utils.translation.trans_real import language_code_re
    File "E:\Programs\Anaconda\envs\taskman\lib\site- 
    packages\django\utils\translation\trans_real.py", line 485
    while (i := lang_code.rfind('-', 0, i)) > -1:
         ^
   SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What is wrong? Do I need to correct invalid syntax in installed Django package? Help me to clarify the issue

Comment: What version of Python do you use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "walrus operator" `:=` [was introduced in Python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#assignment-expressions). You must be using an earlier version of Python.

Since [Django 4.0 only officially supports Python 3.8, 3.9, and 3.10](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/releases/4.0/#python-compatibility), you'll either need to use a newer version of Python or an older version of Django.

Comment: Yes! It's exactly the point. I created new environment with python 3.9, installed Django 4.0 and got an expected directory structure after startproject command. Great, thank you for your attention and help

Answer (score 0):

I don´t know if you did it this way, but try to install django by the command  `python -m pip install Django`
More info [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/install/)

Answer (score 0):

proper commands are:

```
python -m django --version
```

**Django 4.0**

```
django-admin startproject lifetool
```

the project structure will be

```
lifetool/
manage.py
lifetool/
    __init__.py
    settings.py
    urls.py
    asgi.py
    wsgi.py

python manage.py runserver
```

BOOM server is running:

```
Django version 4.0, using settings 'lifetool.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

Comment: This doesn't address the issue in the question. If you use these commands with a version of Python that's too old, as OP is doing, you'll get the same error they are.